# Crop & Resize Images in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, image

I have gone through several plugins and I can't find a plugin that simply resizes and crops images to a specific size when they get uploaded. This is different from simply resizing one side of the image, I need it to resize the smallest side and then crop the largest side so that the image fits in a specific space. WP already does this by default with thumbnails but I need to do this with full-sized images as well. I was going to use: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/scissors/ but it doesn't work with my installation.

Can anyone think of another plugin that does this? Is there a simple way to enable this behavior for full size images by modifying wordpress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does Scissors not work for you because you are using Wordpress 2.9? It appears someone has created a [modified version of Scissors for Wordpress 2.9](http://dev.huiz.net/2010/01/03/wordpress-plugin-scissors-for-v2-9/).

[Max Image Size Control](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/max-image-size-control/) also appears to offer this functionality. I haven't used either of these plugins myself, though. Good luck!

Comment: I finally used max image size control and it worked out, thanks!